# Where is catalase produced?

Tags: cell-biology, enzymes, organelle

I am doing a research project on the peroxisomes, and in it I referenced the enzyme catalase, which breaks down hydrogen peroxide into water and oxygen. However, the assignment asks me to specify the production location of all enzymes, and I cannot find any useful information about where the enzyme is created. I think it is created in the peroxisome itself, but am not so sure of that. Where is catalase produced?

Comment: According to this source https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26858/ , peroxisomes don't have ribosomes. Thus the source of catalase isn't the peroxisome.

Comment: According to [this source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21520/) all peroxisomal proteins are synthesized on **free ribosomes in the cytosol**.